# How to clear expiration date from Azure Key Vault secret?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I was testing expiration dates on a secret in Azure Key Vault, and I'd like to remove the expiration date, but the box is grayed out. Is it possible to remove the expiration?

I set the expiry time using this:

```
Update-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "Keys" -Name "ConnectionStringPPE" -Expires "1/1/2099 12:00:00 AM"
```

I wanted to unset it using this line but this no-ops:

```
Update-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "Keys" -Name "ConnectionStringPPE" -Expires $null
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot unset it once you set the expiry date and it becomes inactive. Only when you create the secret without set the expiry date, it's in the unset state.